# Retrieving value from BehaviorSubject for multiple dynamically created component

Tags: angular, dynamic, rxjs

I'm creating a dynamic preview where I drag and drop and the component is dynamically generated in the preview canvas. The component can be repeated in the same preview canvas. Upon dropping the component setting; eg, the styling and etc is generated too like a toolbox. I've successfully created the element dynamically and the text value in the text component can be change individually. However, when applying the style from the component setting, the style changed on all the text component in the canvas instead of individually. I'm using `BehaviorSubject` to pass the setting to the text component in the service.

**html** *dynamically created component*

```
<editable editableOnEnter (update)="updateText()">
    <ng-template viewMode>
        <div [style.font-style]="selectedStyle">
            {{ textLabel.value }}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template editMode>
        <input type="text" [formControl]="textLabel">
    </ng-template>
</editable>
```

**service**

```
  private textStyle  = new BehaviorSubject('styleText');
  currentStyle$ = this.textStyle.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeStyle(currentTextStyle: string) {
    this.textStyle.next(currentTextStyle);
  }
```

**html** *dynamically created styling component*

```
<div class="type-style">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-widget" (click)="onClickItalic()" >
        <i class="fas fa-italic"></i>
   </button>
</div>
```

**ts** *dynamically created styling component*

```
  currentTextStyle: any;
  constructor(private data: DrawCanvasService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.currentStyle$.subscribe(current => this.currentTextStyle = current);
  }

  onClickItalic() {
    this.data.changeStyle('italic');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by different ways:
1 If you just want to change the style without persist the data you can inject the service in the providers lf the component.
2 You BehaviorSubject could be an object like {[key:string]: string} where the key should be an id from each component and you just update that property on the BehaviorSubject

Comment: no 2 seems like the way to go. but I'm having trouble passing the id from each  component to the component setting that's doing the styling for the component.

Comment: You should upload the code to a stackblitz or codepen to facility the debug and the ideas you have